# Ensure Parallel Invoke don't use to much CPU

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, parallel-processing

I have a C# Program with WCF that use parallel Invoke a bit.

First, every client call is parallel on service side with my WCF service.

I have a class A that contains a List of class B

I can add a list of class B without adding A.

To insert my list of element B I do it in parallel because before adding I do a lot of verification. And same with A

Some Client adds in one time really big list of A elements.

So, I use a parallel invoke for adding each A elements.

I configure it with parallel options to use no more than half of the CPU.
To let other users that do other thing use the CPU.

But the task that Add Class A who is already parallel limited to half of CPU create another Parallel Invoke to Add Class B

For exemple on call of 
InvokeAddClassAList
Create Two thread AddClassA.

And Each AddClassA
Create Two Thread AddClassB

So, I have now 4 Thread.

Is this 4 thread limited to half of CPU?
Or only The Two AddClassA are limited to half CPU and each children Thread can use as much CPU as they want?

```
var pCount = Environment.ProcessorCount / 2;
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = pCount > 0 ? pCount : 1;
Parallel.Invoke(options, actions.ToArray());
```

Comment: Can you share any code sample you did ?

Comment: Parallel execution allows use of CPU capacity when it's available. It's not intended to force a process to use a specific fraction. It just means that an activity doesn't have to be limited to one thread if more capacity is available.

Comment: My purpose is to limite CPU usage for a List of List of Task. even if some cpu is available i don't want it to use more than half

Comment: And about code sample.... It's really big method that why i choose to describe how my thread work instead of giving one messy code sample

Comment: You might think of using [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?view=netframework-4.7.1) . It does not limit amount of CPU utilized, but you can reduce degree of parallel operations, hence, possibly, CPU cores utilization.

Comment: That's what i use but it limite for my list of task. But dos it limite inside every task if a do another parallelism inside?

Comment: "I configure it with parallel options to use no more than half of the CPU. To let other users that do other thing use the CPU." This is simply not possible. You can only limit the number of Threads with this option. It's up to the .Net Runtime, OS and CPU to decide how to handle the task. See [the ParallelOptions reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent tasks
So my first method can't have more than 3 concurent task.
But if in all this concurent task i create some more is it possible to pass 3?
Or the system keep the context and make me wait to never use more than 3 concurrent taks?

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is a resource that should be *used*. Nobody will thank you if it idles. So limiting your process is pointless. You don't even know if there is somebody else using the computer at the time.

You *could* use your own [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation to influence when and how many tasks will be started and when.

But again, there is no point. You should request *as much as possible*. And if you want to be nice to other users, lower your processes priority, so if you want to use 100%, they can still work with their higher prioritized processes.

Comment: Hum i'm not sure it's nice to have CPU at 100% all time. 

But yeah the main goal is if someone launches something that is really long and he knows he will wait a few seconds/minute. I want to let Cpu usage for someone that came after and launch an action that is really short. I don't want him to wait for availability... When I know a task is a long run.  If my CPU is used at 100% it slow users that want something. I have like 20 people connected on the same machin. So i want to dispatch a bit and if someone launch a really big thing let ressource for other...

Comment: Isn't the purpose of MaxDegreeOfParallelism . To reduce usage of amount of thread?

Comment: You seem to think that if you want 100%, you *get* 100%. Every process has a **priority**. Resources are allocated according to this priority. So for example, if you have an endless loop and a browser window, if the endless loop has the higher priority, you won't be able to handle the window. If the window as the higher priority, you will be able to browse without problems, because only the *remaining* resources will be given to the 100% hog. So your target should be to use 100% but you should set the *priority* of your process to low so you get only 100% of *what is left*.

Comment: What makes no sense is to go for normal priority, but less than 100%. You should go as fast as you can and yield for faster people, always going your speed but yielding for nobody means you will always be late and sometimes frustrate others.

Comment: My Service is One application with many process... So he gets the max the OS can give to it at a time. But inside my app i wanted to change a bit and define that this method in particular is never authorise to have 100% of what application is allowed to use at a time T